# How to draw bullet chart in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning, charts, d3

Is there any js library to draw bullet chart in Lightning component ?
I have tried with d3.js and bullet.js in two different approaches but failed.

1. I created lightning component and in helper method, created bullet chart, but it is giving error 
   Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined]
2. By creating chart in visualforce page, but when I use controller in visualforce page, it is not available for Lightning record page.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: on VF page did you check the checbox `available for lightning and Salesforce 1`

Comment: Yes i checked the box